# how can I create index on the basis of column content first 4 letter?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

How can I create index on the basis of column content first 4 letter?

For example I have a table having multiple fields, one field is having name `country`, all Country name is in that table.

```
RANK    COUNTRY
--------------------------
1       Qatar
2       Luxembourg
3       Singapore
4       Brunei Darussalam
5       Kuwait
6       Norway
7       United Arab Emirates
8       Switzerland
9       United States
10      Hong Kong SAR
```

Now I want to do the indexing on `Country` field. But I want the indexing on first 4 letter of that filed data.

Comment: Are you asking for a particular programming language (add a tag, then), or you want the theoretical basis only?

Comment: What you're describing is in effect a hash index, but I'm not sure why you would want to do this on such a short string.

Comment: I think your best option is to make a column COUNTRY_4 and index that.

Comment: Your "best option" is to forget about "first four characters" and simply index the column  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "prefix" index:

```
INDEX(country(4))
```

But I don't recommend it.  There are under 300 countries in this world; you may as well index the full strings.